# If α and β are the roots of the equation $3x^2+5x+4=0$, find the value of $α^3+β^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

If α and β are the roots of the equation $3x^2+5x+4=0$, find the value of $α^3+β^3$

How can I factorize the expression to use the rule of sum and product of roots?

The answer is $\frac{55}{27}$

Comment: $a^3+b^3 = (a+b)(\cdots)$

Comment: $(\alpha+\beta)^3 - (\alpha^3 + \beta^3) = 3\alpha\beta(\alpha+\beta)$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}\newcommand{\be}\beta$ I hope you can
find $u=\al+\be$ and $v=\al\be$. It would be nice if $u^3$ was equal to
$\al^3+\be^3$, but it isn't. Actually
$$u^3=\al^3+\be^3+3\al^2\be+3\al\be^2.$$
We have a deficit of
$$3\al^2\be+3\al\be^2=3\al\be(\al+\be)=3uv.$$
Therefore
$$u^3=\al^3+\be^3+3uv,$$
or
$$\al^3+\be^3=u^3-3uv.$$

Answer (score 1):

Vieta's theorem is the key, like [in your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446243/find-a-quadratic-equation-with-integral-coefficients-whose-roots-are-frac%CE%B1%CE%B2). It gives $\alpha+\beta=-\frac{5}{3}$ with no effort and

$$\alpha^3+\beta^3 = (\alpha+\beta)\left((\alpha+\beta)^2-3\alpha\beta\right) = -\frac{5}{3}\left(\frac{25}{9}-4\right) = \color{red}{\frac{55}{27}}$$
with very simple manipulations.

Comment: you mean $\beta^3$?

Comment: @ab123: sure, sorry, now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Using the general form of quadritic equation, $x^2 -(a+b) x  + ab$,
we get the values of $a+b$ and $ab$.

Now, the expression $a^3+b^3$ can be reduced to $(a+b)^3 -3ab(a+b)$.

Substitute the value of $a+b$ and $ab$ in the above equation.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Kindly use Mathjax. Enclosed your math expressions with $ signs to have a readable answer.

Comment: If you intend $a$ and $b$ to be roots, it should be $x^2-(a+b)x+ab$. Also, I second what Math Lover said. [Here's a guide to MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @ennar that was a typo! ;)

Comment: @MathLover please suggest an edit!!

Comment: I've edited the post for you. Just have a look at the changes I made. Hopefully, this will help you in the future.

Comment: @MathLover thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Rename $a=\alpha$ and $b=\beta$

Since $a$ is a solution of $3x^2+5x+4=0$ we have $3a^2+5a+4=0$ and thus $a^2={1\over 3}(-5a-4)$, so:

$$ 3a^3 = -5a^2-4a = -{5\over 3}(-5a-4) -4a = {13\over 3}a+{20\over 3}$$

the same is true for $b$, so we have

$$9a^3+9b^3 = 13(a+b)+40 = 13{-5\over 3 }+40 = {55\over 3}$$

and thus conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

expanding $$\frac{1}{216} \left(-5-i
   \sqrt{23}\right)^3+\frac{1}{216} \left(-5+i
   \sqrt{23}\right)^3$$ we obtain $$\frac{55}{27}$$